# Fire an function when a request is send to the server by the browser and browser is waiting for a response using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I want to fire a JavaScript function when the browser has send a request for another page and waiting for a response using JavaScript or jQuery.

I don't want to use a windows onload event.I want to fire a function as soon as a click is recorded and the request is send.

Answer (score -1):

try the [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event. It will be executed before leave page.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work . Basically it a loader that loads soon after some one clicks a link on the webpage.

Comment: So when exactly do you want the function be invoked?

Comment: as soon browser send a request similar to progress bar working

Answer (score -1):

you must have used Ajax to send request. So before that you can call that function and on success event .if its progress bar make it 100%